# Не работает программа с GLFW и GLEW

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glfw

Изучаю `OpenGl` по [туториалу](https://habr.com/ru/articles/311234/)  и при попытке запустить скомпилированную программу, ничего не происходит.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    
    std::cout<<"Test";//Строчка не выполняется

    //Init
    glfwInit();//Если данная строка есть - программа ничего не делает
    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);

    //Window

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Openg GL", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window==nullptr){
        std::cout<< "Failed to create GLFW window\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cout<< "Failed to initialize GLEW\n";
        return -1;
    }

    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Команды для компиляции:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -I src/include
g++ -o main31 main.o -L src/lib -l glew32 -l mingw32 -l opengl32 -l glfw3dll
```

`libopengl32.a` скачал с [этого сайта](https://github.com/bakercp-archive/ofMinGW/blob/master/MinGW/lib/libopengl32.a)

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

Попытка запустить main31.exe (cmd):

```
C:\cpp_projects\leranOG\makeout>main.exe

C:\cpp_projects\leranOG\makeout>
```

OpenGL имеется, другие программы использующие opengl+sfml работают

Использую `mingw32 v7.3.0`

`GLFW`: 3.3.8 bin win32

`GLEW`: 2.1.0 win32

ОС: `Windows 10 Pro`

Comment: Запускайте не из консоли, а мышкой из проводника. Увидите всякие интересные ошибки.

Comment: Еще, хорошо бы обновить компилятор. GCC 7.x - старый, сейчас уже 12.х. https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, мне показало что не было dll, я их добавил и всё заработало, а GCC 7.x мне нужен для SFML, т.к. там строго по версиям компилятора

Comment: *"там строго по версиям компилятора"* Это вы где такое прочитали? В том же MSYS2 (см. ссылку) есть SFML в виде пакета, который спокойно работает с последним компилятором.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я смотрел на их официальном сайте

Comment: Можете показать ссылку?

Comment: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/

Comment: Ого! Ну, использовать древний компилятор ради одной библиотеки - это неразумное требование. Если эти файлы правда не работают с более новым компилятором, то их - в мусор, и либо билдить SFML самому, либо, в случае MSYS2, взять оттуда готовую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В структуру проекта необходимо добавить следующие dll-файлы:

- glew32.dll
- glfw3.dll